# New Form Controls are not adding in Angular 7 reactive forms

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to add mat input fields dynamically to an existing form using formArray,with a button click 
This is my component.ts file

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-categories-page',
      templateUrl: './categories-page.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./categories-page.component.css']
    })
    export class CategoriesPageComponent implements OnInit {

      displayedColumns = ['name','username', 'password','email','role','isactive'];
      //users:UserModel[]=[{username:"hello",password:"Hello",name:"Logan"}];
      dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserModel>;
      categoryForm:FormGroup;
      public contactList: FormArray;
      email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);
      username=new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
      password=new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
      name=new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
      errors:any={};
      spinner:boolean=false;





      @ViewChild('dialog',{"static":false}) template: TemplateRef<HTMLElement>;
      constructor( private adminservice:AdminserviceService,private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,public dialog: MatDialog,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}





    get Category()
    {
      return this.categoryForm.get("subcategories") as FormArray;
    }


    addChildCategory()
      {
        console.log("clicked");
        this.Category.push(this.formBuilder.control(""));
      }



    ngOnInit()
    {
      this.getUsers();
      this.categoryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       maincategory:["",Validators.required],
        subcategories:this.formBuilder.array([
          this.formBuilder.control('')

        ])
     });
```

This is my html file

```
<ng-template #dialog>
            <form [formGroup]="categoryForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">


            <ol>
              <li>
                <mat-form-field  [style.width.px]=327   >
                  <input matInput formControlName="maincategory" placeholder="Category Name">

                  <mat-error *ngIf="errors.name">{{errors.name}}</mat-error>

                </mat-form-field>
              </li>




               <div formArrayName="subcategories">

                  <mat-icon style="cursor: pointer;"(click)="addChildCategory()" >add_to_photos</mat-icon>



                <div *ngFor="let sub of subcategories?.controls; let i=index">

                  <mat-form-field  [style.width.px]=327   >
                    <input matInput  placeholder="Sub Category" [formControlName]="i">



                  </mat-form-field>

                </div>

               </div>

                <li>


                  <button mat-raised-button color="primary"
                  type="submit" 

              matTooltip="Click To Submit The Form"
              >Submit</button>

              </li>
            </ol>
          </form>
          </ng-template>

    //


    }

    }
```

I am not getting any error but the input is not getting inserted in the html.Moreover I am opening a dialog window to show the form ,any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: You have to add  new FormControl() instead

Comment: How?? do I add?

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
    this.categoryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      maincategory: ['', Validators.required],
      subcategories: this.formBuilder.array([
        new FormControl()
      ])
    });
  }

Answer (score 0):

To add new child category:

```
addChildCategory()  {
    const arr = this.categoryForm.get("subcategories") as FormArray
    arr.push(new FormControl());
}
```

Comment: Form elements are adding but they are not visible

Answer (score 0):

Use **categoryForm.get('subcategories').controls** or use getter to get access to array of controls in the template

**Try this**

**component.html**

```
 <div formArrayName="subcategories">
  <mat-icon style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="addChildCategory()">add_to_photos</mat-icon>
  <div *ngFor="let sub of category.controls; let i=index">
    <mat-form-field [style.width.px]=327>
      <input matInput placeholder="Sub Category" [formControlName]="i">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
get category() {
  return this.categoryForm.get("subcategories") as FormArray;
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-mat-dialog-dbsh7r)